# Persistent GPU data in Visual Studio AMP?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gpu

Its easy to create a block of GPU memory in CUDA/OpenCL that persists over multiple GPU calls. But how is that done in Visual Studio AMP? The best I've seen is an incorrect answer on another site that says just make local references to host-persistent data. But I know that's wrong because it would still do a host-to-GPU copy every time you instantiate the reference, right?

Surely Microsoft wouldn't go to all the trouble of developing AMP and then neglect a thing that makes it worth using! Any thoughts or ideas welcome.

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 C++11.

Comment: Have you tried something like what is suggested for the second question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25496140/c-amp-transferring-data-async-and-keeping-data-on-accelerator)?

Comment: Thanks, i think that will help, and also the link therein to the AMP book.